# How to upload new version on console and deactivate all previous versions?

Tags: android, apk, policy

I've a version 1.0.5 which was removed by Google for a breach in user data policy. Now a significant number of users were using this version and while the app is removed from Playstore, it's still working for those users. After that any version which I had uploaded got rejected with the same reason pointing towards the same 1.0.5 version.

My question is how do I deactivate this version while uploading a newer version? There is no button to deactivate it and I cannot figure out what to do in the process of uploading in order to deactivate all previous versions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `Deactivate` button is only useful for situations where you have multiple active APKs.

Comment: Hi @RobinHood there is no Deactivate button in the Play Console. Many people over different communities have mentioned that it used to be there but Google has now removed that. The only way deactivation would work is by uploading a new build. But i cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: follow the steps in an answer regarding the policy update

Comment: I believe i'm not clarifying the issue here. So i've fixed the policy violations. But everytime i submit it, it keeps on rejecting the new build and mentions the older version in the rejection reason which is still active.

Comment: do not upload a new version only fulfill the data safety section with relative information regarding the Application and submit the app in review again. Discard the new release until your data safety section is not fulfilled your app functionality it keeps rejecting. Google also requires a sandbox user login to test the app. You have to give sandbox user credentials as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `App Content` in **Policy and Programs** section. After selecting the **Data Safety**
[image]

Fill out the information related to the App
[image]

> Send the App to the Review again

Answer (score -1):

First you need to make application fully compliant with the google data policy, second make sure to upgrade Version Code and version name in module level build.gradle file. After that try to upload the app with higher version level at play store to review. I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Rashid. But the issue i'm facing is that whenever I submit a new release Google rejects it and in the rejection email it always mentions the same older version.
Now i'm looking forward to the steps which should be taken while uploading a new release that will deactivate the older version.

Comment: have you tried from draft folder?